# Why does access to __weak reference in expression not use autorelease pool anymore?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

As the book "Pro Multithreading and Memory Management for iOS and OS X" says: "when an object is accessed through a __weak qualified variable, the object has been added to the autorelease pool" http://bit.ly/QdWX6n

```
id __weak obj1 = obj;
NSLog(@"%@", obj1);
```

The source code is equivalent to the following:

```
/* pseudo code by the compiler */
id obj1;
objc_initWeak(&obj1, obj);
id tmp = objc_loadWeakRetained(&obj1); objc_autorelease(tmp);
NSLog(@"%@", tmp); objc_destroyWeak(&obj1);
```

I tested this code when read this book. And everything was like in a book.
But now I have no objects in autorelease pool. Instead of it assembler says to me that using of weak referenced object looks something like this:

```
objc_loadWeakRetained
* using
objc_release
```

So nothing in autorelease pool at all and objects are releasing right after usage.

The question: what changed and why this is so now? In which cases calling `objc_loadWeak`  and in which just `objc_loadWeakRetained` with the `objc_release`?

Comment: That statement is nonsense. Weak references have nothing to do with autorelease pools at all. A weak reference is a reference to an object which doesn't retain it, so the object goes away if all strong references are gone, even if there are weak references. And when that happens, all weak references are set to nil.

Comment: @Rusik, did you see http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2012/Aug/msg00027.html: "Despite the wording here, the compiler currently often uses objc_loadWeak instead of objc_loadWeakRetained, thus performing an autorelease rather than a release.  This generally extends the lifetime of the retain considerably.  That behavior is not guaranteed, however;  future releases may begin using loadWeakRetained in more circumstances." This however does not explain the why of what you are asking i.e. why this change from objc_loadWeak/autorelease to objc_loadWeakRetained/release.