# Objective-C - weak object is registered in autoreleasepool automatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

I am reading *Pro Multithreading and Memory Management for iOS and OS X with ARC, Grand Central Dispatch, and Blocks* written by Kazuki Sakamoto.

The book wrote:

> When a variable with a __weak qualifier is used, the object is always
>   registered in autoreleasepool.
>
> ```
> id __weak obj1 = obj0;
> NSLog(@"class=%@", [obj1 class]);
> ```
>
> The above source code is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> id __weak obj1 = obj0;
> id __autoreleasing tmp = obj1;
> NSLog(@"class=%@", [tmp class]);
> ```
>
> Why does the object need to be registered in autoreleasepool in order
>   to use the object via the __weak qualified variable? Because a
>   variable, which is qualified with __weak, does not have a strong
>   reference, the object might be disposed of at any point. If the object
>   is registered in autoreleasepool, until @autoreleasepool block is
>   left, the object must exist. So, to use the objects via __weak
>   variable safely, the object is registered in autoreleasepool
>   automatically.

I have given below the program to verify what the author wrote.

```
@interface A : NSObject
- (void) dealloc;
@end

@implementation A
- (void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
}
@end


int main()
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        {
            A *obj0 = [[A alloc] init];
            id __weak obj1 = obj0;
            NSLog(@"end of block");
        }
        NSLog(@"end of autoreleasepool");
    }

    return(0);
}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
end of block
dealloc
end of autoreleasepool
```

**Expected Output:**

```
end of block
end of autoreleasepool
dealloc
```

obj1 is disposed at the end of the block. It's obvious that obj1 isn't registered in autoreleasepool automatically.

If I manually add

```
id __autoreleasing tmp = obj1;
```

The output is expected. obj1 is disposed at the end of the autoreleasepool.

Could anyone tell me what's going on? Is the weak object registered in autoreleasepool automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: as far as i know, every scope is effectively its own autorelease pool, so if you took out those bracers inside the autoreleasepool, it should give you the expected result. i think behind the scenes, at the end of every scope, local variables call their release function, as if it were not arc (and what you would do if you werent using arc)

Comment: i cant remember where i saw this, so maybe if someone can confirm my claim ill write it up as an answer

Answer (score 1):

> When a variable with a __weak qualifier is used, the object is always
>   registered in autoreleasepool.

That is absolute and total nonsense. __weak has nothing to do with autorelease pools whatsoever.

What the compiler does is add the location of the pointer to the list of "weak pointer" locations - note the *location* of the pointer, not the object. So when the object itself is released, all weak variables pointing to it can be set to nil.

And of course the compiler is clever and will optimise that kind of thing away when it can prove that it is not necessary.

What the author says about using weak variables safely is nonsense. The whole *point* of a weak variable is that it doesn't keep the object alive. So preventing the object from going away would be absolute nonsense. The whole idea is that it can go away, so sometimes you will check if the object is still there.

I don't have the book, so I cannot know if you are quoting the book correctly. If you are quoting it correctly, then the book is spouting dangerous nonsense and should be avoided. Well, to be honest, "Pro Multithreading" in a book title is off-putting already.

> Could anyone tell me what's going on? Is the weak object registered in
>   autoreleasepool automatically?

Absolutely, definitely not. That would be absolutely stupid.

Comment: Looks like you are wrong, according to assembly code accessing weak pointer generates a objc_loadWeak call, and from Clang documentation, objc_loadWeak retains and autoreleases the object

Comment: _Accessing_ the variable uses `objc_loadWeak()`. The initial creation/store of the value uses `objc_storeWeak()`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that ARC at the end of each scope decides whether or not to release + dealloc local variables.

from [an article i found on the matter](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/)

> ARC variables are released as soon as the optimizer decides that they
>   are no longer referenced, so the compiler is free to release uicolor
>   after fetching the CGColor. Current compiler implementations do seem
>   to wait until the end of scope, but that’s not guaranteed. The LLVM
>   Project’s ARC notes say: “By default, local variables of automatic
>   storage duration do not have precise lifetime semantics.”

so its seems at the end of the inner scope to your @autoreleasepool, arc is releasing the local variable

Answer (score 0):

I am reading the same book now and I found this part very confusing too. And I wrote a very similar program to test it and it didn't work. After some googling I've found that weak pointer is added to autorelease pool indeed:

> Precondition: object is a valid pointer which either contains a null
>   pointer or has been registered as a __weak object.
>
> If object is registered as a __weak object, and the last value stored
>   into object has not yet been deallocated or begun deallocation,
>   retains and autoreleases that value and returns it. Otherwise returns
>   null. Equivalent to the following code:

```
id objc_loadWeak(id *object) {   
    return objc_autorelease(objc_loadWeakRetained(object)); 
}
```

> Must be atomic with
>   respect to calls to objc_storeWeak on object.
>
> Rationale: Loading weak references would be inherently prone to race
>   conditions without the retain.

But I still can't understand why object is released instantly, not when autorelease pool is drained. My guess some serious magic like compiler optimizations is involved.

Comment: The code in the question is not equivalent to the code in the book. There's a strong pointer in scope when the assignment is made to the weak reference. That strong pointer will be released at the end of the braced block. There's also no _access_ of the weak reference, which is what uses `objc_loadWeak()`. In the code in the question, the weak reference is being _created_: `objc_storeWeak()` is the function to look at, and it does not retain the object or put it in the pool.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but can you be so kind to give an example code to replicate situation when weak pointer is added to autorelease pool? Just to close all questions here.

Comment: I whipped this up: https://gist.github.com/woolsweater/88437df1061bbe1b3a9791cf8384d4a6 but to be honest I'm not completely clear what's going on. There's a release as the second autorelease pool ends, but it wasn't paired with a send of `autorelease` or `retain`.

Comment: Code makes sense, but an absence of autorelease and retain... it's definitely a mystery to me. Not sure I will have time to investigate further in next couple of days but anyway thanks a lot to clarify it on paper at least!

Comment: The compiler can optimize out autorelease in favor of retain/release if it deems that it's feasible. And seems recently by default `objc_loadWeak` is not used anymore, in favor of `objc_loadWeakRetained` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020588/why-does-access-to-weak-reference-in-expression-not-use-autorelease-pool-anymo