# How to understand that "When a variable with a __weak qualifier is used, the object is always registered in autoreleasepool"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

The book named Pro Multithreading and Memory Management for iOS and OS X writed that

> Why does the object need to be registered in autoreleasepool in order to use the object via the __weak qualified variable? Because a variable, which is qualified with __weak, does not have a strong reference, the object might be disposed of at any point. If the object is registered in autoreleasepool, until @autoreleasepool block is left, the object must exist. So, to use the objects via __weak variable safely, the object is registered in autoreleasepool automatically.

I do not understand why __weak need the variable is exist. __weak does not retain the variable.if the variable is not exist.The __weak variable should be nil.Why this book say that "If the object is registered in autoreleasepool, until @autoreleasepool block is left, the object must exist".

And if it is registered in autoreleasepool .Which pool does it is registered?I do not alloc a autoreleasepool when I use __weak.Who can tell me why.

Answer (score 2):

The book you are reading is at least confusing, and may be sometimes outright wrong, in its presentation of `__weak` and `__autoreleasing` qualifiers. (The book is a translation, this may account for the sometimes confusing language used.)

References stored into `__weak` qualified variables are *not* also automatically added to the autorelease pool, that is contrary to the purpose of weak variables.

What does happen is that under some circumstances when a reference is loaded from a weak variable it is placed in the autorelease pool by the compiler to avoid a race condition (between an object being released and its reference being loaded from a weak variable). You do not need to concern yourself, at least directly, with this - the compiler is simply insuring that a reference you have loaded from a weak variable is valid for the time you use it.

You can find other comments on this book in the question [Objective-C - weak object is registered in autoreleasepool automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083137/objective-c-weak-object-is-registered-in-autoreleasepool-automatically)

HTH